# Get all binance coins via API

Tags: api, binance, cryptocurrency

I am looking to get all the currencies traded in binance via API.
I came across this link:
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo
But unfortunately he only shows some of the coins (For example COS is missing).

Anyone have a suggestion on how to get all the trade coins?

Answer (score 2):

`exchangeInfo` ([docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information)) is the right endpoint.

It's returning pair objects with the `COS` currency in the `symbols` array, currently under indexes 585, 586, and 1837.